# Por que o GIT está ignorando uma pasta e outras não dentro do wwroot?

Tags: git, github

Sou novo com o git e estou utilizando-o para controlar um projeto asp.net core no VS 2017. Eu configurei o arquivo .gitignore, mas estou tento problemas quando crio pastas. Eu criei, dentro do diretório wwwroot, uma pasta chamada "backups" e ela foi ignorada (não devia). Em seguida, criei uma segunda pasta com o nome de "uploads" e ela não foi ignorada (fez certo). Preciso fazer com que ele não ignore a pasta "backups"... Alguém sabe como configurar o .gitignore para isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

//.gitignore
    .gitignore

```
## Ignorar no Projeto Retaguarda
.vs\Retaguarda\v15\Server\sqlite3\storage.ide
.vs/**/storage.ide

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
[Xx]64/
[Xx]86/
[Bb]uild/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# DNX
project.lock.json
artifacts/

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opendb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile
*.VC.db

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
*.sap

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml
nCrunchTemp_*

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml

# TODO: Un-comment the next line if you do not want to checkin
# your web deploy settings because they may include unencrypted
# passwords
#*.pubxml
*.publishproj

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config
# NuGet v3's project.json files produces more ignoreable files
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets

# Microsoft Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Microsoft Azure Emulator
ecf/
rcf/

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/
BundleArtifacts/

# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!*.[Cc]ache/

# Others
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/
orleans.codegen.cs

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# GhostDoc plugin setting file
*.GhostDoc.xml

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions

# LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
ModelManifest.xml

# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe

# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/
```

Comment: As pastas estão vazias?

Comment: Sim... Gostaria de não ignorar essas duas pastas(backups e uploads), mas ignorar os arquivos uue serão gravados dentro delas.

Answer (score 1):

## Problema

O Git ignora as pastas que estão vazias.

## Solução

Uma solução é simplesmente adicionar um arquivo chamado ".keep" na pasta correspondente. Agora você pode preparar e confirmar esse arquivo, como consequência, também adicionar a pasta ao controle de versão.

O arquivo .keep não é um nome "mágico", mas sim uma convenção. Além disso, o arquivo não serve a nenhum outro propósito além de tornar sua pasta visível para o Git.

[Fonte](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/add-empty-folder-to-version-control)

Answer (score 0):

A pasta Backup está sendo ignorada pois está no arquivo .gitignore! Até mesmo pastas com o prefixo Backup, serão ingnoradas, já que foi declarado "Backup*", ou seja, qualquer pasta que comece com Backup será ignorada!

1. Retire do arquivo .gitignore a linha Backup*/
2. Se a pasta estiver vazia, é necessário criar algum arquivo dentro dela para que seja versionada, mas isso não é uma boa prática, pois se não existe arquivos nela, não tem motivos para ser versionada.

Comment: Certo @egomesbrandao!! mas e se eu quiser ignorar apenas os arquivos dentro delas?

Comment: Ignorar e manter ela vazia no repo? Não rola... Mas vamos distranchar melhor: 
Vc tem uma pasta que são gerados arquivos nela e não quer manter nada? Coloca Backup/*, dai todos os arquivos não vão subir para o repo, e importante: nem a pasta, já que pasta vazia não é versionada.
- Se você está tentando criar essa pasta no repo, por que precisa dela para rodar o projeto, a melhor maneira é na inicialização da aplicação você checar se ela existe, senão criá-la.